# Callback function for Angular ui-grid rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to know what is the callback function that fires after Angularjs grid is rendered meaning all its cells are rendered a function like $.ready()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The figured out the function is 
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered()

Answer (score 7):

there are two `functions` you can use, if you want to execute on ui-grid ready then use `renderingComplete`

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    gridApi.core.on.renderingComplete($scope, function() {
        //code to execute
    });
}
```

if you need `callback` on data change use `rowsRendered`

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered($scope, function() {
        //code to execute
    });
}
```

Comment: These functions are almost what I want, however they don't still work properly. If I check the number of input elements using these function I get 0, however it should show the right value (in my case I have 12).

Comment: what do you mean by number of input elements?

Comment: I mean that if I use `jQuery('input').length` (these inputs are supposed to be inside the grid cells) I receive "0". But if I do it with a timeout (solution that I don't like) it shows me 12, therefore the grid is not 100% rendered at this point.

Comment: same problem here. I need to apply filters on columns after the grid is rendered. If I do the renderingComplete() and inside I try to access the columns list, it is empty cause grid it's not rendered

Comment: @xero399 did you try `$timeout` or `setTimeout`?

Comment: @SanjayNishad Thanks! putting the timeout inside the renderingComplete without setting time works fine!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `$timeout` for your issue

http://jsfiddle.net/8nuwQ/100/

Comment: No thats not suitable solution

Comment: Indeed, timeout solutions are not reliable.